# How to calibrate multimeters?

Tags: multimeter, multimeter, calibration

Without buying an expensive calibration tool, how can I accurately calibrate my multimeters?

Comment: Why do you need to calibrate? If you need to calibrate in order to prove to someone else that your meter is up to snuff, you might want to contact a calibration service - they have all that expensive equipment, so you don't have to.

Comment: I'm only a hobbyist with low budget. The goal of the calibration is that my 3 different multimeters do not show three very different values for the same measured object :) I've already made same lenght measurement cables for them from low resistance silicone wire, next step is to calibrate them to a good reference.

Comment: How far apart do they read right now on what value resistor?

Answer (score 13, accepted):

You can buy a few 0.1% resistors to calculate resistance ranges cheaply.

Voltage is tricker - if you have access to several meters you can 'calibrate by consensus', as it is improbable that they will all go out in the same direction.

Another option is buy a precision voltage reference IC - e.g. AD581 is 10V with 0.1% accuracy.

Current can also be done using voltage across a known, accurate resistance.

Answer (score 4):

Bring them to your university or employer, and see if you can get them to calibrate them for you the next time they do their calibration run.

No, I'm serious.  I expect that most schools and employers will be happy to see that their students and employees are developing their skills outside of the school/work environment, and when you've got a production line set up for a hundred meters already, the addition of one (or a few) more meters isn't that big of a deal.