# What Ways to Calibrate a Multimeter?

Tags: multimeter, calibration

How can one calibrate a multimeter, like a UT61E or any other multimeter in the 50 ~200 $ pricemark, when one does NOT have an expensive FLUKE nor a friend who has a FLUKE)

Comment: possible duplicate?  http://electronics.stackexchange.com/questions/5507/how-to-calibrate-multimeters

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Very generally and at the most basic, you need a precision voltage reference and resistors.  Obtaining 0.1% is fairly easy, for resistors it's straightforward, and for voltage references look up "precision voltage reference" (something like [this](http://search.digikey.com/scripts/DkSearch/dksus.dll?Detail&name=AD1580ARTZ-REEL7CT-ND)), and bias it with 0.1 to 1 mA.

The actual calibration procedure will vary from meter to meter, so you will need to dig up the appropriate documents.

Answer (score 1):

Basically, there are lots of adjustable resistors on the multimeter PCB - don't forget to mark original positions of all of them before you start.

You ether get a precision resistor references (read datasheet on temperature coefficient), or find a guy with precision equipment in your city to compare the readings.